# OpenMP offloading data race

Tags: c++, openmp, offloading

I'm currently working on a project to invert matrices on the GPU using OpenMP. However, when normalizing a row of a matrix I have a data race.
The code looks like this:

```cpp
#pragma omp target data map(tofrom: matrix[0:dim*dim], iden[0:dim*dim]) map(alloc: factor)
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {

// fix data race on cpu, this should not be necessary
#pragma omp target update from(matrix[i * dim + i])
    factor = matrix[i * dim + i];
#pragma omp target update to(factor)

#pragma omp target teams distribute shared(factor)
    for (int x = i; x < dim + i + 1; x++) {
//barrier doesn't help
//      float factor = matrix[i * dim + i];
//#pragma omp barrier
        if (x < dim) {
            matrix[i * dim + x] /= factor;
        } else {
            iden[i * dim + x - dim] /= factor;
        }
    }

...
}
```

The data race happens because `matrix[i * dim + i]` will get replaced by `1.0` at some point during the calculation. Replacing it in the last iteration didn't fix the problem either.
Maybe you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!